# find intervals not in tree

Tags: algorithm, interval-tree

I have a bunch of (date)intervals which might overlap. The intervals come from different sources. I want to 'flatten' this 'timeline' and then find all intervals where no interval was.

If you look at: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/
to the "A more complex example" section. I thus want to find the intervals where no composer was alive.

How do I do that? and how would you implement such a thing in PHP?
Does PHP also have some easy functions for building the tree?

many thx!

**edit**
My input is a number of arrays (2, 3 or 4) with each containing start and stop dates like so:

```
 $myarray1[0]['start']['date'] = 'somedate'
 $myarray1[0]['stop']['date'] = 'somedate'
 $myarray1[1]['start']['date'] = 'somedate'
 $myarray1[1]['stop']['date'] = 'somedate'
 $myarray1[2]['start']['date'] = 'somedate'
 $myarray1[2]['stop']['date'] = 'somedate'
```

the same goes for myarray2, myarray3 and so

Comment: BTW: The birthdate for Franz Shubert is wrong. It should be 1797, not 1779.

Comment: You can look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/q/748516/1088243 to understand the algorithm.
You do not need to build a tree but just a hash which hashes smaller dates with smaller integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Basic algorithm

For each composer, create two objects. One is a birth object with the composer's name and the year of birth. The other is a death object, again with the composer's name and the year of death.

Now sort these objects together.

Keep an `int`, initialised to `0` for `num_composers_alive`.

Iterate through the ordered list of objects. Every time you encounter a birth object, increment `num_composers_alive`. Every time you encounter a death object, decrement `num_composers_alive`.

While incrementing or decrementing, every time you hit a death and decrement, check if `num_composers_alive` went to 0. If so, you just entered a period when no composer was alive. Output that number or store it somewhere. Every time you hit a birth and increment, check if `num_composers_alive` is now 1. If so, you just ended a period when no composer was alive. Output that number or store it somewhere.

### Implementation

This is going to depend on the form of your input and output. I don't believe PHP has a native concept of trees, but I might be wrong on that. Try implementing the above, and open a separate question if you get stuck.

To be honest, I'm not sure why you need trees to solve the above problem anyway, but maybe it's for something else.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need trees either, but a more linear-time approuch is also becomming very messy (and rather inefficient). What else would you suggest?

Comment: This is not messy. The sort step typically takes N log N, which would be the same for a tree-based thing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm in steps

1. Define a function that translates a date object to an integer (and vice versa). This is a place where you may need to optimize the translation to make all numbers as small as possible. A date from past must have smaller number then a date from future
2. Initialize array of numbers. Set all bits to `0`. Make sure the size of the array matches the largest date number (from step 1).
3. Iterate over the date ranges
4. Mark date range in the array with `1`s. *Use date translated into a number (step 1) as an index in the array.*
5. Translate all indexes with `0`s back to the date intervals.

Runtime complexity O(N). Space complexity O(N).